# Bash: Syntax highlighting for tail (with awk)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm using tail and awk to do syntax highlighting on my log file.

This is my highlighter:
**tailError.sh**

```
 tail -f error.log | awk '
 /INFO/  {print "\033[1;37m" $0 "\033[39m"} 
 /ERROR/ {print "\033[31m"   $0 "\033[39m"}
 /WARN/  {print "\033[33m"   $0 "\033[39m"}
 /DEBUG/ {print "\033[0;37m" $0 "\033[39m"}
 /at com.adobe.training/ {print "\033[31m" $0 "\033[39m"}
 '
```

This is very close to
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/how-to-have-tail-f-show-colored-output

Let's say, this is my log file (**error.log**):

```
*INFO* Really?
*WARN* Take care
*ERROR* Doh!
Exception in thread "main" NullPointerException
    at com.adobe.training.methodWithNPE (MyClass.java:123)
    at somewhere.else (Servlet.java:234) --- This line should be printed, too --
--- This line and the next one are missing. ---
 --- How do I output these lines? ---
```

And the output looks like that:
[image]

As you can see, these lines from my log file are missing:

```
at somewhere.else (Servlet.java:234) --- This line should be printed, too --
--- This line and the next one are missing. ---
--- How do I output these lines? ---
```

How do I output these lines?

I guess, there should be sth. like an *else* in my awk statement:

```
awk '/INFO/ { print $0 } /ERROR/ { print $0 } /EVERYTHING_ELSE/ { print $0 }'
```

Thanks
Bernhard

UPDATE:
Here is the updated **tailError.sh:**, which works as expected.
Thank you, jas.

```
tail -f error.log | awk '
    /INFO/  {print "\033[1;37m" $0 "\033[39m"; next} 
    /ERROR/ {print "\033[31m"   $0 "\033[39m"; next}
    /WARN/  {print "\033[33m"   $0 "\033[39m"; next}
    /DEBUG/ {print "\033[0;37m" $0 "\033[39m"; next}
    /at com.adobe.training/ {print "\033[31m" $0 "\033[39m"; next}
    {print $0}
'
```

Comment: Glad I could help!, but just to mention that often it's good to give some time for alternate solutions. To be honest, for your particular use case I think that @B98 has a bit nicer idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `next` for else-ish behavior in awk.

```
/INFO/ {print 1; next}
/ERROR/ {print 2; next}
{print 3}
```

> The next statement forces awk to immediately stop processing the current record and go on to the next record. This means that no further rules are executed for the current record, and the rest of the current rule’s action isn’t executed.

Thus, this can be read as:

```
If record matches /INPUT/ then print 1
else if record matches /ERROR/ then print 2
else print 3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can introduce a state variable, and whenever there is no special "marker" like "INFO", you'd reset colors to some default. Or, you change color state only when there is a "MARK".

```
tail -f error.log | awk ' BEGIN { colcode = 0 }
 /INFO/ { colcode = "1;37" }
 /ERROR/ { colcode = "31" }
 /WARN/ { colcode = "33" }
 /DEBUG/ { colcode = "0;37" }
  { print "\033[" colcode "m" $0 "\033[39m" ; colcode = 0 }
```

Note that the print statement has no selecting RE and is therefore the "else" line.

Answer (score 0):

For java, log4j, I use:

```
tail -f -n 400 /var/log/log.0 | \
awk '
  {matched=0}
  /INFO/         {matched=1; print "\033[0;34m" $0 "\033[0m"}
  /INFORMACIÓN/  {matched=1; print "\033[0;34m" $0 "\033[0m"}
  /WARNING/      {matched=1; print "\033[0;93m" $0 "\033[0m"}
  /ADVERTENCIA/  {matched=1; print "\033[0;93m" $0 "\033[0m"}
  /ERROR/        {matched=1; print "\033[0;91m" $0 "\033[0m"}
  /SEVERE/       {matched=1; print "\033[0;91m" $0 "\033[0m"}
  /failed/       {matched=1; print "\033[0;91m" $0 "\033[0m"}
  /GRAVE/        {matched=1; print "\033[0;91m" $0 "\033[0m"}
  /Caused by/    {matched=1; print "\033[0;96m" $0 "\033[0m"}
  matched==0                 {print "\033[0;36m" $0 "\033[0m"}
'
```